# saving all the results in file

Tags: python, multithreading

In this code, all of the results are not appended to the results file. Only the last IP response is written to the results file. where I am doing wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated. The results filename is timestamped.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time

timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
timesec = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

raw_list = []
def ping(host):
    results_file = open("results" + str(timestr) + ".txt", "w")
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", host, "-n", "1"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    response = p.communicate()[0]
    for i in response.split("\n"):
            para =i.split("=")
            try:
                if para[0].strip() =="Minimum":
                    latency =para[3].strip()
                    onlylatency = list(latency)
                    latencyfin = onlylatency[0]
            except:
                print("time run")

    if "Received = 1" and "Approximate" in response:
        print(f"UP {host} Ping Successful")
        results_file.write(f"{host},UP,{latencyfin},{timesec}"+ "\n")
    else:
        print(f"Down {host} Ping Unsuccessful")
        results_file.write(f"{host},Down,0,{timesec}" + "\n")
    results_file.close()

with open(r'input.txt', "r") as server_list_file:
    hosts = server_list_file.read()
    hosts_list =hosts.split('\n')
num_threads = 1
number = 0
while number< len(hosts_list):
    # print(number)
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=ping, args=(hosts_list[number+i],))
        t.start()
    t.join()
    number = number +1
```

Comment: You need to open the file in access mode where it doesn’t create a new file each time it is opened…

Comment: Use the `”a”` as your second argument instead of the `”w”` on you `open()` call. Tried to put the full line here, but pasting isn’t working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the access mode ‘a’ when opening the file.

See the change below -

```py
def ping(host):
    results_file = open("results" + str(timestr) + ".txt", "a")
```